# How to create ajax functions to control a form

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I am developing a form in laravel that shows products and projects of a certain department. I need to create a function in js/ajax so I can allow users to choose a product, and once that happens, the project field in the form should show a drop-down menu of all the projects related to that product. How can I do that? Below is the code for the form, which has two fields (Produto) and (Projeto).

```
<form action="/arquiteturas/store" method="post" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<div class="form-group  {{$errors->has('combo_produto')? ' has-error' : '' }}">
   <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Product</label>
   <div class="col-md-8">
   <select class="form-control search-select" name="combo_produto" 
 id="combo_produto">
                  <option value="0">Choose</option>
                  @foreach($produtos as $value)
                    <option @if(old('combo_produto')==$value->id){{'selected'}}@endif value='{{$value->id}}'>{{$value->nome}}</option>
                  @endforeach 
                </select>
                 <span class="help-block">
                  @if($errors->has('combo_produto'))
                    @foreach ($errors->get('combo_produto') as $error)
                      <b>{{$error}}</b>
                    @endforeach
                  @endif
                 </span>
              </div> 
            </div>

              <!--Projet.-->
              <div class="form-group  {{$errors->has('combo_projeto')? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                  <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Project</label>
                   <div class="col-md-8">
                     <select class="form-control search-select" name="combo_projeto" id="combo_projeto">
                       <option value="0">Choose</option>
                       @foreach($produtos as $value)
                      <option @if(old('combo_projeto')==$value->id){{'selected'}}@endif value='{{$value->id}}'>{{$value->nome}}</option>
                       @endforeach 

                     </select>
                      <span class="help-block">
                       @if($errors->has('combo_projeto'))
                         @foreach ($errors->get('combo_projeto') as $error)
                           <b>{{$error}}</b>
                         @endforeach
                       @endif
                      </span>
                   </div> 
                 </div>
```

I am sharing an excerpt of code for a similar funcionality of a form in which the user selects a product from a dropdown menu. Once that happens, a list of related branches is shown in the branch dropdown menu.

```
loadProdutos()

$("#combo_produto" ).change(function() {

  clearCampos('combo_branch')

  if(checkItemSel('combo_produto')){

    $('#div_produto').removeClass('has-error');
    $('.help-produto').empty();

    var produto_id = document.getElementById('combo_produto').value
    $('#combo_branch').prop("disabled", false);
    loadbranchs(produto_id )

  }else{

    insertCombo('combo_branch', '0','Selecione')

    $('#combo_branch').prop("disabled", true);

  }

});

$("#combo_branch" ).change(function() {

  if(checkItemSel('combo_produto')){

    $('#div_branch').removeClass('has-error');
    $('.help-branch').empty();

  }

});

function loadProdutos()
{
  var request = $.ajax({

      method:"GET",
      url:"/validar_fontes/request_produtos",
      dataType:"json",

      beforeSend: function () {

        blockPage();

      },
      complete: function() { 
          // unblock when remote call returns 
          $.unblockUI(); 
      } 

    });

    request.done(function(e){

      if(e.status){

        if(e.produtos.length>0)
        {
          $('#combo_produto').append('<option value="0">Selecione</option>');
          $('#combo_produto').val("0").trigger("change");

          for(var i=0;i<e.produtos.length;i++)
          {

            $('#combo_produto').append('<option value="'+e.produtos[i]['id']+'">'+e.produtos[i]['nome']+'</option>');

          }

        }else
        {

          $('#combo_produto').append('<option value="0">Nenhum produto encontrado</option>');
          $('#combo_produto').val("0").trigger("change");
        }
      }

    });
}

function loadbranchs(produto_id)
{
  var request = $.ajax({

      method:"GET",
      url:"/validar_fontes/request_branchs",
      data:{produto_id : produto_id},
      dataType:"json",

      beforeSend: function () {

        blockPage();

      },
      complete: function() { 
          // unblock when remote call returns 
          $.unblockUI(); 
      } 

    });

    request.done(function(e){

      if(e.status){

        if(e.branchs.length>0)
        {
           $('#combo_branch').append('<option value="0">Selecione</option>');
           $('#combo_branch').val("0").trigger("change");

          for(var i=0;i<e.branchs.length;i++)
          {

            $('#combo_branch').append('<option value="'+e.branchs[i]['id']+'">'+e.branchs[i]['nome']+'</option>');

          }

        }else
        {
          $('#combo_branch').append('<option value="0">Nenhuma branch encontrada</option>');
          $('#combo_branch').val("0").trigger("change");
        }
      }

    });

}
```

Comment: See the documentation of jquery Ajax https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ .

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to create a end point (server side method in laravel) which will take the "producto" and return all "projecto" related to selected "producto"
2. Then on change event of "producto" dropdown in javascript/jquery you need to call the avobe created method and pass the producto value.
3. The projecto list should be key value pair so that it can be populated in dropdown projecto

Here is a draft page what you are trying to achieve, let me know if you can understand by this.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function PopulateContinents() {
        var producto = $('#combo_produto').val();

        if (producto == "") {
            alert("Please select a valid product");
        }
        else {
            $('producto').empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Loading...</option>');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: pageUrl + '<enter the url of server method created>',
                data: '{producto: ' + producto + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(datas){
                    for(i=0; i<datas.length; i++)
                    {
                        $('#combo_projeto options').append("<option value='"+datas[i].Value+"'>"+datas[i].Text+"</option>");
                    }
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>

<form action="/arquiteturas/store" method="post" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<div class="form-group  {{$errors->has('combo_produto')? ' has-error' : '' }}">
   <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Product</label>
   <div class="col-md-8">
   <select class="form-control search-select" name="combo_produto" 
 id="combo_produto">
                  <option value="0">Choose</option>
                  @foreach($produtos as $value)
                    <option @if(old('combo_produto')==$value->id){{'selected'}}@endif value='{{$value->id}}'>{{$value->nome}}</option>
                  @endforeach 
                </select>
                 <span class="help-block">
                  @if($errors->has('combo_produto'))
                    @foreach ($errors->get('combo_produto') as $error)
                      <b>{{$error}}</b>
                    @endforeach
                  @endif
                 </span>
              </div> 
            </div>

              <!--Projet.-->
              <div class="form-group  {{$errors->has('combo_projeto')? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                  <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Project</label>
                   <div class="col-md-8">
                     <select class="form-control search-select" name="combo_projeto" id="combo_projeto">
                       <option value="0">Choose</option>
                       @foreach($produtos as $value)
                      <option @if(old('combo_projeto')==$value->id){{'selected'}}@endif value='{{$value->id}}'>{{$value->nome}}</option>
                       @endforeach 

                     </select>
                      <span class="help-block">
                       @if($errors->has('combo_projeto'))
                         @foreach ($errors->get('combo_projeto') as $error)
                           <b>{{$error}}</b>
                         @endforeach
                       @endif
                      </span>
                   </div> 
                 </div>

                 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Ritesh for the code above. I have tried to implement it, with no success so far. I am starting out, and I have managed to get an internship in php, and I have no idea about js or ajax, and I was given the task above. I have looked into code of similar tasks already done in the system and that I would like to share as well.